# Sequelize sum function not working (Cannot read properties of undefined)

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a view called `observations` which contains a JSON column called `metadata` and another column called `calculated_total_cost`.

I'm trying to run the following query:

```sql
SELECT sum(calculated_total_cost)
FROM observations_view
WHERE metadata IS NOT NULL AND (metadata->>'dag_run_id')::text = 'abcd';
```

using Sequelize. I've generated the models using `sequelize-auto` and so far it works as expected.

When trying to run the following call:

```
observations_view
      .sum("calculated_total_cost", {
        where: {
          metadata: {
            [Op.not]: null,
            [Op.and]: Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn("metadata->>'dag_run_id'"), "abcd"),
          },
        },
      })
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
```

I get the following error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'calculated_total_cost')

Am I missing something or misunderstanding?

Thanks in advance for your answer!

Comment: Stacktrace of the error?